# Convergence of Bounded Sequence Satisfying $2c_n \leq c_{n+1} + c_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(c_n)$ be a bounded sequence satisfying $2c_n \leq c_{n+1} + c_{n-1}$.
>
> (a) Let $x_n = c_{n+1}-c_n$. Show that $(x_n)$ is increasing.
>
> (b) Show that $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
>
> (c) Show that $(c_n)$ converges.

As $x_n = c_{n+1}-c_n \leq \frac{1}{2}c_{n+2}-\frac{1}{2}c_n$ and $x_{n+1} = c_{n+2} - c_{n+1} \geq \frac{1}{2}c_{n+2}-\frac{1}{2}c_n$, we have $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$ and thus $(x_n)$ is increasing.

I am stuck with the other parts. It would make sense to establish 0 as upper bound of $x_n$, but I cannot seem to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Outline:** The sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded. This is because by the Triangle Inequality we have $|x_n|\le |c_n|+|c_{n+1}|$.

Since $(x_n)$ is bounded,  some subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges. Since $(x_n)$ is non-decreasing, the full sequence $(x_n)$ converges.

Show that if the sequence $(x_n)$ has limit $b\ne 0$, then the sequence $(c_n)$ cannot be bounded.

Finally, what does the fact that $(x_n)$ is increasing and has limit $0$ say about the monotonicity of $(c_n)$?

Remark: To show the sequence $(x_n)$ is non-decreasing, it would have been a little more efficient to rewrite the given inequality as $c_{n+1}-c_n\ge c_{n}-c_{n-1}$.